# Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme In Android Studio 3.1

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-layout-editor

The Android Studio 3.1 layout preview fails to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in the current theme.

```
Failed to instantiated one or more classes.
 Exception shown are :-
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
```

Answer (score 17):

**This happened due to use of alpha version SDK 28**

We need to change the `android { ... }` in "build.gradle" in app file

`compileSdkVersion 28` to `compileSdkVersion 27`

`targetSdkVersion 28` to `targetSdkVersion 27`

Also, try to change implementations like

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'` to

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

Hope this works!

For **Android Studio v3.1.***, in addition we need change:

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'` to

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

Comment: android requires to target the latest version, anyway to fix this still targeting 28?

Comment: No,we can't . Since,the Android SDK version 28 is still in beta and rc-01 version as on this date , we have to wait until we get a stable version of SDK 28

Comment: This did work for me also, Thanks for sharing.
Remember for Android Studio v3.1.* also change support to: implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
The errors still continue in the error list, but it works now fine without any problems just igonring them.

Answer (score 5):

you can fix this issue by adding this script to the app module `build.gradle`, in the `android` section

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion "27.+"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can confirm that this does the trick for 3.1.3 but just wondering if there is any benefit to this over explicitly setting version 27 as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220258/635522 ?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the current version of Android Studio (3.1.3) as I was encountering the same thing. I downloaded the beta build from here and opened my existing project and the errors disappeared.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/?utm_source=android-studio

Not exactly a fix but hopefully it will get you back up and running.

Comment: Thank You , 'JOSH' It's main error of 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' was Solved. But I have encountered with a new problem help me with it too it says - tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

**1.** **com.android.support:appcompat** [stable version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0) 28.0.0 is released. So no need to downgrade version. Just use 28.0.0.

```
def supportVersion = "28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
```

You can ignore design library if you don't need it.

**2:** You also need to update your **`compileSdkVersion`** & **`targetSdkVersion`** to remove some gradle warnings.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

> Never use alpha versions of any library, because alpha, beta and rc
>   versions may have bugs. And you don't want to face these types of errors often.

#### Important Suggestion

I suggest you migrate to `androidx` because android will not update support library after 28.0.0, all updates will be available to `androidx` package only. [Check related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563).

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Android Studio 3.2.

Answer (score -1):

Go to app/res/styles and change the Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar for this one Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: This fix may work in older versions of Android Studio, but not in 3.1.3.