# Android Studio always start a project with version 28

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I create a new project and it starts with a Render Problem I can solve it by downgrading the `implementation` inside the file build.gradle(Module: app)

The issue itself is that this Render Problem occurs everytime I create a new project. Is that a setting that needs to be changed on the IDE to build the project using a compatible version? (e.g. `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`

The default version of every project starts with `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'`

Comment: That's more like a bug which we're facing too. Are you asking to avoid downgrading to `appcompat` v27 everytime you start a project btw?

Comment: I can work with the project if I downgrade it. I just find lame having to do it everytime I create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

That version (`28.0.0-rc01`) is depending on your **installed SDK manager packages**. So, if you are trying to get rid of those render problems and preview issues and etc, you'll need to downgrade from `28.0.0-rc01` to `27.1.1` which you are already doing it so, go to SDK manager and delete the latest buggy version `28.0.0-rc01`.

But, this is *not recommended*, it might cause problems.

**It will be like:**

> platform-tools v27
>
> build-tools v27

And maybe more which Android Studio will let you know but, downgrading is not recommended. Instead, use this workaround for e.x for Preview issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650706/4409113

Which somehow bypasses the issue.

**Or**, you can download the Canary version ([**UnStable version**](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/)) of *Android Studio* which helps you coding with the latest tools (`28.0.0-rc01` in your case).