# elements of app not showing up in design preview

Tags: android-studio, event-handling

When i try to add image in the grid layout in design preview it is not showing up in the preview and it is not showing any error but still elements are not showing in layout edit.

[image: it is showing like this but not showing up the elements of layout editor. i have also change the themes from theme editor but nothing is happening]

Comment: Code shown in images is not prefered,, instead, copy and paste the text with the code formating option you have. You should show us the error details, aswell as the xml layout text.

Comment: Find your answer in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50856622/5180017)