# How can I fix 'Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme' render

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I got this error when I created a navigation drawer activity and I don't know how to fix it.

> Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Comment: That's the 28.1.1 bug and it has been discussed for too many times in here! Try using 27.1.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme In Android Studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856622/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme-in-android-studio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292487/failed-to-find-style-coordinatorlayoutstyle-in-current-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert this line into the theme you are using for the app

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK 28 is unfortunately introducing this error on Android Studio

Check your build.gradle (Module: app) file and change:

compileSdkVersion 28

targetSdkVersion 28

To:

compileSdkVersion 27

targetSdkVersion 27